# Function alias template gives an error with GCC, but not with VS2015

Tags: c++11, gcc, visual-c++, c++14, syntactic-sugar

The next code snippet shows how to I simplify user code, making library slightly more complicated. In other words add some syntactic sugar.

```
 Channel const& joinMulticast(NetAdres  const &group) const;

 /// Auto-construct NetAdres.
 /// joinMulticast() can take any combination of args and passes them to NetAdres::NetAdres() constructor. No need to write many overloads
 template<typename... Y>
 auto joinMulticast(Y&&... y)
    -> decltype(joinMulticast(std::declval<Y>()...))
 {
    return joinMulticast(NetAdres(std::forward<Y>(y)...));
 }
```

`VS2015` eats silently, but GCC cannot digest this code with fatal error:

```
template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use -ftemplate-depth= to increase the maximum)
         -> decltype(joinMulticast(std::declval<Y>()...))
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

Comment: Your declaration doesn't make any sense. It's essentially `auto f() -> decltype(f());` - it tries to declare a function whose return type is the type this function would return; a circular reasoning. Did you perhaps mean `decltype(joinMulticast(NetAdres(std::forward<Y>(std::declval<Y>())...)))` ? As to why MSVC accepts it - I predict you would get an error if you try to actually call this beast. MSVC notoriously doesn't implement two-phase translation of templates, deferring all semantics checking to the point of instantiation.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Even that's not enough since the second overload is still preferred over the first.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, this did not help. The same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *in my case* return type is always the same, simplify construction:

```
template<typename... Y>
Channel const& joinMulticast(Y&&... y)
{
  return joinMulticast(NetAdres(std::forward<Y>(y)...));
}
```